# Simple web project deploys on Tomcat 6, not on JBoss 6

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jboss, http-status-code-404, jboss6.x

I use the latest Eclipse (Java EE development).
I have two servers defined in the servers view: Tomcat 6, and JBoss 6 (I have to use these).

I am trying to test the following simple web application: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-create-hello-world-application-spring-3-mvc/

When I start Tomcat 6 (from eclipse), I can access the project home page.

Then, when I stop Tomcat 6 and start JBoss 6, when I try to access the project home page - I get HTTP status 404.

What is wrong here? What may I be missing?

I do not know where I am supposed to look for errors.
I can see this project is not being deployed in JBoss but I am not sure why (I guess I forgot something basic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Servers view in Eclipse so you can see your jboss server. Right click on your JBoss server and choose Add and Remove. This lets you choose which application to add to your server.

Okay I was able to recreate the issue you have I believe. You should see the errors in the Console in eclipse. Is your console displaying anything from JBoss? I'm getting an error because my workspace has a space in it. I'm going to try to fix that and see if it works.

---

I finally got this to work on JBoss 6.1. Apparently there is a bug between JBoss 6.1 and those Spring libraries the project uses the 3.0.1 libraries.

You need to download newer libraries for Spring. You have to changes these to fix some deployment issues even after you get it to deploy to the right location. I found them all here: [Spring 3.1.3](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/library/version/detail?name=org.springframework.spring&version=3.1.3.RELEASE)

So once I saved those, I copied them to the lib folder and removed the 3.0.1 files. The next issue I had was getting eclipse to use the right Deploy folder. I have jboss installed in c:\jboss-6.1-final. In Eclipse you have to double click on your jboss server to open the JBoss Overview Page, there is a tab at the bottom of that labeled Deployment. On that screen I had to choose, Use the JBoss deploy folder, which uses the one on my C: drive instead of the one Eclipse defines with the JBoss Tools. When you choose run on server, it should then create a folder in your c:\jboss-6.1-final\server\default\deploy folder now.

[image: JBoss Overview/Deployment Screen]

Comment: I did it of course. You can download JBoss 6.1 Final, download the sample project from the link above, try to deploy it as you said above, and see that it was not deployed correctly. What I just said works with JBoss 5, 7 - but not 6. Why? I'm using the eclipse Jboss plugin from Jboss tools.

Comment: I posted more information above in my response. Let me know if you still run into issues. I think I probably had the same problems you had so hopefully I can help you through it if you still have problems.

Comment: thanks! It worked! What made you think of Spring 3.0 as the problem? I think they update the Jboss plugin (I just update my eclipse a couple of days ago). I believe the problem might be with JBoss 6, since Spring 3.0 does work with JBoss 7.

Comment: I had an error message from JBoss about some virtual directory or file problem so I searched for that and the tutorial name. Stumbled over someone saying they had to update those libraries.